# Selenium webdriver for java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have downloaded selenium for java, unzipped it and put it in my project folder.
Also I downloaded the appropriate webdriver for MS Edge and put it in the folder.
(P.s. I wrote my script in python and it works. Now I want to write it in Java and extend it).

When I import in the main file "import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;" it underrings org.openqa and then it says "The import org.openqa cannot be resolved".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> The import org.openqa cannot be resolved

This means that class is not on your classpath.

You have to ensure that the CLASSPATH has pointed to the jars folder.

Comment: How can I solve this problem in VS ?

Comment: You can read [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects).